# Double command execution with instanceof and HashMap

Tags: java

I'm really flummoxed by this one. After having some problems managing separate HashMaps for each child class, I decided to try using instanceof to make things simpler with a HashMap of the Parent class that will include any number of each of the child classes. I came up with this test code:

```
static  HashMap <Integer, ant> antMap = new HashMap();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ant is parent to antF, antSo, and antB
    ant testSc = new ant();
    antF testF = new antF();
    antSo testS = new antSo();
    antB testB = new antB();

    antMap.put(testSc.ID, testSc);
    antMap.put(testF.ID, testF);
    antMap.put(testS.ID, testS);
    antMap.put(testB.ID, testB);
    ant grand = new ant();
    int loop = 0;

    for (int s = 1; s < 5; s++){
        grand = antMap.get(s);
        loop++;
        if(grand instanceof ant){
            System.out.println("type " + grand.type + grand.ID + "Loop " + loop);
        }
        if(grand instanceof antF){
            antF work = (antF) grand;
            System.out.println("type " +  work.type + work.ID + "Loop " + loop);
        }
        if(grand instanceof antSo){
            System.out.println("type " + grand.type + grand.ID + "Loop " + loop);
        }
        if(grand instanceof antB){
            System.out.println("type " + grand.type + grand.ID + "Loop " + loop);
        }
    }
```

I put the loop counter in there to see if the for loop was doubling up somehow but the output is:

```
type Scout1Loop 1
type Forager2Loop 2
type Forager2Loop 2
type Soldier3Loop 3
type Soldier3Loop 3
type Bala4Loop 4
type Bala4Loop 4
```

I see the parent class (labeled scout here) executes once correctly. The constructor class in ant assigns an ID based on the number of ants, so the Forager should be Forager2, Soldier should be Soldier3, etc.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the child classes are executing twice. The loop counter shows this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: you can see I tried a couple different things within the for loop to get the expected results.)

(I did try to tag this as homework, although this is not a specific solution.)

Comment: Can you show the class definition of each type? Like `public class ant...` and `public class antF...`

Comment: Constructors as follows 

 `public ant(){
 // ants will always be hatched in the Queen node at 13,13
  this.ID = ++numberOfAnts;
  this.age = 0;
  this.type = "Scout";
  this.x = 13;
  this.y = 13;
  this.lifespan = 3650;
  this.location = "1313";
 }

 public antB(){
  super();
  this.type = "Bala";
 }
 public antF(){
  super();
  this.type = "Forager";
 }
 public antSo(){
  super();
  this.type = "Soldier";
 } `

Answer (score 1):

One way for you to get the output you are seeing is to have `antF`, `antSo` and `andB` all extend class `ant`. In this case, when `grand` is an instance of class `antF`, the following two if-s will both return true: `grand instanceof ant` and `grand instanceof antF`.

A simple way to fix this is to change the last 3 `if`-s to `else if`-s, or to put `continue` in each of the if blocks.

Comment: My apologies first for the poorly formatted code in the reply and for neglecting to say that each class does indeed extend the ant parent class. I just copied the constructors because I have other functions, some quite lengthy, in the child classes. But they do extend.

Comment: Signature example: public class antB extends ant{

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your classes extend `ant`. Remember, extends pretty much means "is a". For example: `public class Dog extends Animal` means a Dog "is a" Animal.

Given that, it will always execute the first `if` statement and then the proper one below it. To resolve this, make the whole thing one big `if-else` statement and place the if for `grand instanceof ant` as the last statement. So like this...

```
if(grand instanceof antF){
    antF work = (antF) grand;
    System.out.println("type " +  work.type + work.ID + "Loop " + loop);
}else if(grand instanceof antSo){
    System.out.println("type " + grand.type + grand.ID + "Loop " + loop);
}else if(grand instanceof antB){
    System.out.println("type " + grand.type + grand.ID + "Loop " + loop);
}else if(grand instanceof ant){
    System.out.println("type " + grand.type + grand.ID + "Loop " + loop);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Ascalonian! This helped out greatly with a couple different aspects of the program. Your explanation caused a eureka moment. Apologies for the late reply but I definitely wanted you to know it helped so much!

Comment: Glad it helped! Best way to show appreciation is to vote for my answer :)